# Backup database on local pc

Tags: sql-server, backup, sqlcmd

I am using this script to backup database on computer A:

```
sqlcmd -U MyDatabase -P MyPassword -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation = 'c:\shared', @databaseName='MyDatabase', @BackupType='F'"
```

everything works fine, but I decided to store backup files to computer B. I shared folder on computer B, which is accessible from:

```
\\computerB\shared
```

I changed backup script to include new backup location:

```
sqlcmd -U MyDatabase -P MyPassword -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation = '\\computerB\shared', @databaseName='MyDatabase', @BackupType='F'"
```

But when I run this, I am getting an error:

> Cannot open backup device '\computerB\shared\MyDatabase_FULL_101
> 22022_232734.BAK'. Operating system error 5(Access denied .). Msg
> 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-C28934ASNF1\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I don't understand why am I getting `Access denied`. I can easly eccess `\\computerB\shared` from file explorer on computer A. What is wrong there?

Comment: Your SQL Server Service account was started by a user that doesn't have permission to access the shared folder. to better understand you can view the related Links:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver16   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89701/sql-server-service-account-windows-privileges-and-rights

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 3201 Operating system error 5(Access is denied.) Creating backup on network drive](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102532/error-3201-operating-system-error-5access-is-denied-creating-backup-on-networ)

Answer (score 1):

> I can easly eccess \computerB\shared from file explorer on computer A.

When you access a share from file explorer as you did, your credentials are passed to the remote computer, but when you execute the backup command either SQL Server service account or the [computer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/service-accounts-computer) is passed to access the share. If the share security has no entry allowing the proper account, you might get the error message you described.

A computer account in your case would be something like `YourDomain\ComputerA$`. You can verify which account is being used checking event viewer on **ComputerB** filtering by event id 4624:

[image: Event Viewer event id 4624]